# How can I do concurrent/simultaneous user testing for uploading a file from 1000 users?

Tags: testing, concurrency, jmeter

one of the requirements from a client for a platform my company develops is that 1000 users should be able to upload a file at the same time. Ive considered and tried using jmeter but as much as I found out, we would have to put in 1000 user credentials in the HTTP authorization manager. Is there any other tool that could make the process easier?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you having problems entering 1000 user credentials? Or managing them? Or generating them?

Comment: yes its the entering 1000 user credentials, since we would also have to create this many users in the platform itself

Answer (score 0):

Well-behaved load test must simulate real usage of the system under test as close as possible, ideally with 100% accuracy

1. If it's not possible to upload the file without being logged in - you need to be logged in (or authorized by other means)
2. If the system doesn't allow multiple sessions from one credentials - you will have to use 1000 separate login/password combinations
3. I don't think HTTP Authorization Manager will accept more than one username/password combination for the same [domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_domain_name) and [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), most probably you will need to put 1000 credentials to the CSV file and then read them using CSV Data Set Config, another option is [getting the usernames from the database via JDBC PreProcessor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-automatically-pull-data-from-a-db-for-your-performance-test) or using [Redis Data Set](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/) Config depending on where the users are stored.
4. If you need to execute 1000 requests at exactly the same moment - take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as well.